# Caesar cipher seeded from previous (shifted) character

Tags: python, caesar-cipher

For fun, I am trying to run a caesar cipher on a string where each character is shifted by the previous character in the string. The initial character is obviously not shifted and used to shift the second, the second character is used as the seed for the third character, etc

Encoding appears to be working as intended; decoding on the other hand...

```
key = "a"
word = key + "shop"

print(word)

coded = ""
for i, val in enumerate(word[1:]):
    coded += (chr(((ord(word[i]) + ord(val) - 97) % 26) + 97))

print(key + coded)
encoded = key + coded

decoded = ""
for i, val in enumerate(encoded[1:]):
    decoded += chr(((ord(encoded[i]) - ord(val) - 97) % 26) + 97)

print(key + decoded)
```

My Maths appears (to the naive eye) correct. Does the encoding have some property that I am not aware of that does not allow for reversing of this?

Example output using the inputs above:

```
ashop
alsow
amqbp
```

Obviously I would like the `amqbp` to be `ashop`. Moving the -97 around does not help (not even sure why it would if it did).

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Your encoding loop appears to be incorrect. I would expect S shifted by A to be T. But your output is L. Maybe try encoding `za`, which should result in `za` to see where you might be going wrong. As a guess, it looks like the problem is that you are taking the modulus of the character code and not the characters index in the alphabet. Eg. For `a` you end up doing `97 % 26` instead of `0 % 26`.